# Accessing serial port by Python 2.5 with ceserial module on windows ce 5.0

Tags: python, windows-ce

I have downloaded ceSerial and successfully communicate with serial ports. I have successfully write the data to the port but I am not able to read the data from the ports. It is getting connected to the port but it is not able to read the values. Below is my code snippet for reading the data from the port.

```html
from time import sleep
import ceserial

ser = ceserial.Serial(port="COM1:",baudrate=9600,bytesize=8,stopbits=ceserial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=ceserial.PARITY_EVEN)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

#data = ''
while True:
    data = ser.read(9999)
    if len(data) > 0:
        print 'Got:', data
    sleep(0.5)
    #print 'not blocked'

ser.close()
```